# движение при скроле

Tags: html, jquery, css

Есть такой кусочек кода:

```js
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();
  if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      $(".baloon1 img").css("width", "+=10px");
    });
  } else {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      $(".baloon1 img").css("width", "-=10px");
    });
  }
  lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<main>
  <header>
    <div class="mega"></div>
    <div class="baloon1"><img src="img/baloon1.png"></div>
    <div class="baloon2"><img src="img/baloon2.png"></div>
    <div class="baloon3"><img src="img/baloon3.png"></div>
  </header>
  <section>
    Hello World
  </section>
</main>
```

То есть по идее, при скролле вниз и вверх должны происходить увеличение и уменьшение картинок, но при установке свойства `overflow:hidden`, скролла нет (его и не должно быть) ничего не происходит. Код работает только если страница скроллится, но тогда не видно эффектов увеличения, тк они уходят вверх вместе со скроллом.

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, HTML-код

Comment: добавил код внизу

Comment: То есть вы хотите, чтобы ваш header был фиксировано сверху страницы?

Comment: он не сверху, он на всю страницу, а при скроле на нем двигаются объекты: и как только они сдвинутся куда нужно у боди overflow hidden убирается и начинается скролл

Comment: position: fixed пробовали?

Comment: а как тут fixed поможет